# UnsatisifiedLinkError - Unable to load dependent libraries

Tags: c++, dll, java-native-interface, dependencies, installshield

I have developed a Java applet that loads my C++ dll through the `loadLibrary` function. From there, my applet calls some native methods that are implemented in the C++ code. I have created an InstallShield installer that puts the C++ dll in the required location on my client computers.

Everything works just fine on my development PC, but when I try testing on a "fresh" client computer that does not have anything but the JRE installed, I am getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries`. I don't know if there is something else I need to include. I checked using DependencyWalker and below is what I saw.

[image]

Is there anything out of the ordinary that a fresh windows install would not include? What else can I do to determine what dependency my dll cannot find on the client?

Comment: Does the other machine have the VS2010 C++ runtime installed? IIRC it doesn't necessarily install as standard.

Comment: No, the client machines will not have VS installed. In my InstallShield project, I have included the `Visual C++ 10.0 CRT (x86)` and `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redist Package`, but it does not help.

Comment: You still have to install the VS2010 C++ *runtime* libraries if you want your C++ executable to work on these machines. They don't need an install of Visual Studio itself.

Comment: I edited my last comment. Are those not the correct runtime libraries I need?

Comment: MSCOREE.DLL indicates that you require the .NET framework also. Do you know which version?   BTW having a Java VM process call a native process that then uses CLR seems like a lot of infrastructure.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I am already including `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Client` in my installation. Sorry, I didn't think it was relevant or I would have mentioned this. And the infrastructure is complicated, but it works and was our only option.

Comment: You mean it works on your machine? :) I can't determine with the available information if .NET 4.0 client is sufficient.  You may need Full depending on what assemblies are referenced. You may also need 4.5.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Yes it works on my machine, but I figured it would because I have all the development tools on it. The .NET application that is invoked by the C# is targeting `.NET Framework 4'. Do you think that the version of .NET I include is the culprit? It seemed to me like the C++ Runtime version was the problem, but I would take your word over mine.

Comment: It's hard to say. All of your dependencies are going to have to be resolved so it could be one or more failures.  Also realize that when you run CLR in process like that it's "sticky".  IE if the process first fires up CLR 2.0 and then tries to fire CLR 4.0  it'll throw a BadImageFormatException. What that would look like when it bubbles up through the JNI is beyond me.  Sorry.